# Property of transpose of matricies

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m$x$n$ matrix. Show that the matrix $A^{T}A$ has the property that $x^{T}(A^{T}A) \ge 0$ for every $x \in \Bbb{R}^{n}$

I was thinking of breaking it into case of the invertability of A but I'm not sure how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $x^T A^T A x = (Ax)^T (Ax) = \|Ax\|^2 \ge 0$.